# How to search through parameter object

Tags: c#

I am having trouble when generating my data back from having param as object.

I have created a class that serves only to the purpose to send data however the data are not List and Group however I can see the data there I just don't know how to access it

```
public class ProcessIdentityGeneratedData
{
    public List<Item> Document { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

then I am sending my data

```
var processIdentityGenerated = new ProcessIdentityGeneratedData();              
processIdentityGenerated.ProcessIdenityDocument = Pages;
processIdentityGenerated.TaskGroup = taskGroup;
await navigationService.NavigateToAsync<DocumentRecognitionResultViewModel>(processIdentityGenerated);
```

and then I am searching through

```
 public override async Threading.Task InitializeAsync(object data)
 {
     IsInitialized = false;
         
     try
     {
          if(data is ProcessIdentityGeneratedData processIdentityGeneratedData)
          {
              if (data is Group Group)
              {
                 _activeTaskGroup = group;
              }
              if (data is List<Item> item)
              {
                 foreach (var result in item)
                 {
                 }
              }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are checking if `data` is a `ProcessIdentityGeneratedData`, but then you want to check the properties of that typed variable:

```
 public override async Threading.Task InitializeAsync(object data)
 {
     IsInitialized = false;
     
     try
     {
         if (data is ProcessIdentityGeneratedData processIdentityGeneratedData)
         {
             if (processIdentityGeneratedData.Group is Group group)
             {
                 _activeTaskGroup = group;
             }

             if (processIdentityGeneratedData.Document is List<Item> item)
             {
                 foreach (var result in item)
                 {
                 }
             }
```